# OpenGL games cannot launch fullscreen, only vulkan

Tags: games, opengl, fullscreen

For about a month now, I cannot open OpenGL games in fullscreen.

They just start windowed with borders at a very low resolution and behave strangely:

- mouse movements trigger desktop environment actions, like Dash-to-dock for gnome, even if mouse is captured and not visible
- the window cannot always be moved

This happens to OpenGL games of all kinds, e.g. HL2/source games from Steam (with and without steam linux runtime), SuperTuxKart as flatpak and native games from gog.

For some games, but not all, I can use a workaround, by changing the settings to be windowed with a lower resolution, then close and restart the game and then make it fullscreen, when it is running, but this does not work for all games and it takes some time and is annoying.

I don't have this issue with vulkan games or games using wine and DXVK.

I have the following setup:

```
Ubuntu 20.10 with vanilla Gnome and X.Org (but happens also when using wayland)
Intel i7 4770K
AMD RX Vega 56 (VEGA10, DRM 3.38.0, 5.8.0-33-generic, LLVM 11.0.0)
RAM: 16 GB DDR3 (XMP deactivated)
```

I don't know where to start and what else to tell, but if you need more information, just ask.

Comment: Same exact issue for me (Ubuntu 20.10) -- tried launch options and several other remedies, no luck. Searching high and low for answers